# The sum of all the outputs (digits, the_number) is correct... it is 72, I just dont know how save it in a variable, or how to return the sum

Tags: python, recursion, cumulative-sum

def sumdigits(number, start):

```
if number > 0:
    if start == True:
        new_number = ((number % 10) * 2)
        digits = (new_number % 10) + (new_number // 10)
        print(digits)
        sumdigits((number // 10), False)


    elif start == False:
        the_number = (number % 10)
        print(the_number)
        sumdigits((number // 10), True)
```

sumdigits(7992739871005, False)

Answer (score 0):

Add the result of calculation to a variable each time, and return that variable at the function's end.

```
def recursion_is_fun(num) :
    sum = 0
    sum += calculate_whatever(num) + recursion_is_fun(num % 10)
    return sum
```

And good luck with the rest of your homework ;)